# CentOS Disk Full - Unable to locate largest files/dirs

Tags: centos

I have a very strange problem, my hdd on my centos server is showing 99% usage. I executed several commands to list largest files, but it didn't show anything larger than 9.9G which is the web directory. Here some output:

```
[root@desync-arpa /]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       453G  421G  8.6G  99% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        97M   53M   40M  58% /boot
/dev/sda4       2.0G   68M  1.9G   4% /tmp
/dev/sdb        459G  643M  435G   1% /mnt/disk2


[root@desync-arpa /]# du --max-depth=1 -h /
4.0K    /srv
1.1G    /home
339M    /etc
4.0K    /media
445M    /mnt
568M    /root
du: cannot access `/proc/26016/task/26016/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/26016/task/26016/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/26016/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/26016/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
188K    /dev
7.7M    /bin
4.0K    /selinux
284K    /tmp
16K     /lost+found
0       /sys
15M     /sbin
5.6G    /var
52M     /boot
26M     /lib64
8.0K    /opt
259M    /lib
1.3G    /usr
9.6G    /
[root@desync-arpa /]#
```

Combined, all folders make up to 18G of space. I'm really stuck finding all those big files, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to try the command line utility called NCDU, based on ncurses. It will scan your disk and allow you to surf through it with ncurses interface. This is example:

```
--- /tmp ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  393.7MiB [##########]  web_www_2015-02-17.tar.gz                      
   57.8MiB [#         ] /builder
   23.3MiB [          ] /config-prod
   15.0MiB [          ]  web_db_2015-02-17.sql.gz
```

You can just move cursors and with return key drill deep into directories.

To install it just run:

```
 # yum install ncdu
```

Note: you'll need EPEL repository on EL5/6 for ncdu.

Later, to run it on a specific FS:

```
 # ncdu -x /path/to/mountpoint
```

-x means - only scan current FS.

Edit:
If you still can't find files that are taking disk space, it's possible that they were deleted but are still held open. That can happen with log files for example. To look for those files, run the following command:

```
# lsof | grep deleted
```

To delete those files, you need to stop processes which are holding them. Another way to free up the disk space is to take a look at proc filesystem, find those file handles, and null the files. File name will be the last column of the output, so just copy it and find a symlink pointing to it in /proc, and then null the file:

```
# > /proc/<pid>/fd/<number>
```

Comment: I already did that, showed same results...

Comment: I added another possible cause to my answer

Comment: Ah yeah, I got a bunch of them... how do I remove those ?

Comment: Added another edit.

Comment: Yes so to kill that one: ircd      24559      circ   43w      REG                8,2     12433232   11931073 /home/circ/ircd3/logs/fuserlog (deleted)

Comment: I have to type: > /proc/24559/fd/11931073

Comment: Okay, i still can't figure out how to kill those files, will have to give google a try. Thank you very much for your help sir !